# Внедрение C++ проекта в Android Studio

Tags: android, c++, opencv, native

Работал с OpenCV на C++, теперь пришло время сделать это на андроиде. Как правильно подключить старый проект С++ к JNI?

Comment: Не понял, кто это минусует? Нормальный же вопрос. Видимо минусаторы не знают, что в Android'е можно на плюсах :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Скачать [NDK - Native Development Kit](https://developer.android.com/ndk)
2. Настроить NDK - конкретно определиться с [toolchain](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/standalone_toolchain)
3. Посадить свои исходники в дерево `src/jni`
4. Написать make файлы для построения исходников: `Application.mk` и `Android.mk`
5. Прописать в Gradle правила построения (я этим не пользуюсь - потому не подскажу, собираю обычно с командной строки)
6. Написать jni интерфейсы - связки между C++ и Java кодом
7. Собрать, в итоге вы получите 3 или 4 либы для разных платформ: `ABI`, `X86`, `ARM` и т.д.

Возможно инструкция слегка устарела, я уже давно не кодил С++ под Android

Comment: Да, инструкция полностью устарела, а вопрос получил минус потому, что оп не потрудился зайти по первой же ссылке в гугле, в которой можно найти актуальную инструкцию. Собственно и ответ на такой вопрос по сути может ограничится этой же самой ссылкой на оф доки.

Comment: @user7860670 напишите свой ответ. Мне тоже было бы интересно, документация документацией, а живой пост на совсем другое